# I have a cardano internal error

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-node, haskell, haskell-language-server

I ran the Cardano node command and it was fetching new tips for like a minuet then i get this error:

cardano-node: internal error: Unable to commit 1048576 bytes of memory
(GHC version 8.10.4 for x86_64_unknown_linux)
Please report this as a GHC bug: report a bug · Wiki · Glasgow Haskell Compiler / GHC · GitLab

here is a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

what's your hardware specification?

That error is thrown by RAM depletion.
You may be able to tune RTS parameters, check it out [here](https://forum.cardano.org/t/solving-the-cardano-node-huge-memory-usage-done/67032)

Answer (score 0):

upgrading the RAM may avoid this error

Comment: https://downloadmoreram.com/

Answer (score 0):

This message appears when the process runs out of memory. Usually, increasing the amount of memory will solve the problem, but not always. Try completely replacing the memory, if it's not soldered to the board.

If that doesn't help - report an issue to the Cardano team.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others above, allocate more RAM to this system.
Check the IOG specs for minimum RAM needed, I think it's 16GB now.

You can also increase your swap space to say 20GB as a temp work around - this is not ideal but is quick to action.
Use command `free -h` to check RAM and swap space usage.

Also make sure you have enough disk space on the volume where the chain is being saved. Use command `df -h`